# .NET DirectoryServices Find methods use UTC or local time?

Tags: .net, datetime, active-directory

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.findbylogontime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the find methods (like FindByLogonTime and FindByBadPasswordAttempt) of the `UserPrinciple` and `ComputerPrinciple` classes use UTC time to filter results.  However, testing shows these methods seem to take local time as input, while the resulting objects use UTC for their time properties and need to be converted to local time.

Here's an example that seems to correctly list all users with a failed login attempt on the server since 6am local time:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, dcServer);
        PrincipalSearchResult<UserPrincipal> uFailed = UserPrincipal.FindByBadPasswordAttempt(pc, DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(6), MatchType.GreaterThan);
        string s = "";
        foreach (UserPrincipal u in uFailed)
        {
            s += u.SamAccountName + ": " + Convert.ToDateTime(u.LastBadPasswordAttempt).ToLocalTime().ToString() + "\r\n";
        }
        Console.Write(s);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Note the UTC conversion for the LastBadPasswordAttempt property, but not in the FindByBadPasswordAttempt filter.

I'm nervous about putting this into production without knowing if I'm missing something (likely) or if the MSDN docs are wrong.  The code runs on the DC it's querying, so should be no timezone issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN docs are accurate, you just need to pay attention to the `.Kind` property of the `DateTime` values that you pass in.

If you dig through the reference sources or disassembly far enough, you will find that the `DateTime` value you're passing ultimately gets passed to [`DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc.aspx), which does take the `Kind` into account in its behavior.

So you can pass in a value based on `DateTime.UtcNow`, which has a `.Kind` of `DateTimeKind.Utc` and it will work, or you can do like you are currently doing and passing `DateTime.Now` which has a `.Kind` of `DateTimeKind.Local` and that local time will be converted to UTC before the query.  Just be sure that you recognize that this is the local time *of the computer that is running the code*.  If there's any chance that this is not the same time zone as your user, then you might need to use `TimeZoneInfo` to get the UTC time equivalent of some other local time zone.

If for some reason you decide to pass in a date that you construct yourself, it will probably have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  For this particular function, that will be treated as if it were UTC.  This is not necessarily true for all date/time functions, so be careful with that.

Also, in the output, there's no need to call `Convert.ToDateTime` when the value you're working with is already a `DateTime`.  For that matter, you don't even need the `ToString` in this code, unless you plan to pass a format specifier.  And again, if your user is possibly in some other time zone, don't use `.ToLocalTime`, use one of the methods on `TimeZoneInfo` to do the conversion instead.

One other tiny optimization, you can use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now.Date` if you want.  (It doesn't make a difference, other than it's slightly more readable.)

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for your help -- that helps me understand what's going on and the tips are welcome and appreciated.